# Function naming, which level of abstraction should be used

Tags: function, naming-conventions, naming, software-design

We have such use case in application:

```
If page visitor is a crawler, then redirect him to home page.
```

These are two ways we have developed to implement that in code:

```
if (isPageVisitorACrawler(visitor)) {
    return redirectToHome();
}
```

```
if (shouldRedirectVisitorToHome(visitor)) {
    return redirectToHome();
}
```

Ok. So I believe first version is much more informative, but others say that second version is better in matter of adapting. Meaning that if we have to add another condition when user has to be redirected to home, it will be easier and cleaner with second version.

```
if (isPageVisitorACrawler(visitor) || isPageVisitorBanned(visitor)) {
    return redirectToHome();
}
```

```
if (shouldRedirectVisitorToHome(visitor)) {
    return redirectToHome();
}
```

Second is still the same at this level.

My question is, when should we wrap such functions into bigger (more general) functions, or if we should at all?

I remember Uncle Bob saying that we should not mix level of abstractions in one function. I believe, function should only call functions that are one level below of its level of abstraction and `shouldRedirectVisitorToHome` seems like it's on the same level, not below.

I hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say neither one.

`isPageVisitorACrawler(visitor)` makes it to specific to the "page visitor", but makes it seem it's not directly related to it.

`shouldRedirectVisitorToHome(visitor)` implies a specific use case.

Without knowing the specific on how you determine if the `visitor` is a crawler (I assume `visitor` has a `UserAgent` or `IP`/`Host` property), the most logic assumption would be to make it `visitor.IsCrawler()` and `visitor.IsBanned()` and determine the action in something like

```
public class Visitor 
{
    private string userAgent;
    private UserStatus status = UserStatus.Active;

    public bool IsCrawler() 
    {
        return userAgent.Contains("Google Bot");
    }

    public bool IsBanned()
    {
        return status == UserStatus.Banned;
    }
}

// In your controller
if(!security.HasAccessTo(visitor, page)) 
{
    return RedirectToHome(); 
}

// example of basic implementation of HasAccessTo
public bool HasAccessTo(Visitor visitor, Page page) 
{
    if(visitor.IsCrawler() || visitor.IsBanned())
    {
        return false;
    }

    List<GroupPermission> permissions = permissionsRepository.GetPermissions(visitor);
    foreach(GroupPermission permission in page.Groups) 
    {
        if(permissions.Contains(permission))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    // if no permissions were found, refuse
    return false;
}
```

This will also make your code easier to read and easier to reuse the logic which determines if the visitor is a crawler or banned. Every developer, even new developers who are not familiar with the project, will instantly understand the code and what it is supposed to do.

The idea behind the "Rich Domain Model" is to put as much logic that belongs to an domain entity in it as possible and make sure the domain entity can keep itself in a valid state.

All other logic, that can't be put into an rich domain model, goes into service or factory classes. This will make changes easier, as you apply it to the domain entity and only have a thin service layer instead of anemic domain models and monolithic service layer which becomes hard to maintain as your problem domain grows.

Answer (score 0):

I think like most have said, in terms of growing your redirection cases at later dates due to different reasons, it would be better to go with "shouldRedirectVisitorToHome(visitor)"

I would always wrap function calls into a more generic call once there are more than 2 child cases that could reach the same result.

Edit: I would also have a generic call even with a single child case if I thought more would come in the future

Answer (score 0):

"isPageVisitorACrawler(visitor)" is more close in meaning to the use case description. But, second one is more preferable if you want to give the function more generic feel. Depends on your need. But, you should not use generic implementation of this method if you are planning to make underlying implmenetation of **isPageVisitorACrawler** function with full of if and else condition. that violate the OCP part of SOLID oop principle i guess.